# Label to be align at the left of the input in jquery ui modal

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

My HTML:

```
<fieldset>
            <label for='descSorteo'>
                Descripción Sorteo</label>
            <input type='text' value='Hoalaa' name='descSorteo' id='descSorteo' class='text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all' />
            <label for='idPremio'>
                Id Premio</label>
            <input type='text' name='idPremio' id='idPremio' class='text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all' />
            <label for='descripcionPre'>
                Descripción</label>
            <input type='text' name='descripcionPre' id='descripcionPre' class='text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all' />
            <label for='tipoPre'>
                Tipo de premio</label>
            <select id='tipoPre'>
                tipoPremioOptions
            </select>
        </fieldset>
```

I want my label stay align at the left of the input ex:

```
[Label][input]
[Label][input]
[Label][input]
```

At this moment i got something like:

```
[Label]
[Input]

[Label]
[Input]

[Label]
[Input]
```

Im using jQuery UI modal dialog Form, Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit the HTML at all? If you made it a UL with each LI containing a label and an input then float the labels left that would work.

Comment: @Kishore im using the css integrated in the jQuery UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
input, select {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

**Example** - http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/HpSc8/

Answer (score 0):

Use the proper markup:

HTML

```
<button class="whatever"> Click me</button>
```

Make it a Jquery UI object:

JS

```
$('button').button();
```

And override the Jquery UI defaults:

CSS

```
.ui-button {
    text-align: left
}
```

For the icon, just put a [Fontello](http://fontello.com/) class on it.